# Select boolean expression inside dictionary using lambda expression

Tags: .net, collections, .net-3.5, dictionary, lambda

I have a dictionary declared like this.

```
public static Dictionary<int?, List<int?>> pegMap = new Dictionary<int?, List<int?>>();
```

Now I'm trying to check a whether the list inside the dictionary contains some value where dictionary key is some value.

```
if (pegMap.Select(y => y.Value.Contains(disc)).Where(x => x.Equals(key)))
{
    peg = (int)key;
}
```

But the compiler is angry and throwing me an error like so -

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<bool>' to 'bool'
```

What am I doing wrong here. Please help.

Comment: Your description is really unclear, particularly around: "whether the list inside the dictionary contains some value where dictionary key is some value". That just doesn't make any sense. If you could given an *example* that would really help...

Comment: @JonSkeet Assume `x` is the dictionary key I want to find. Now after finding the `KeyValuePair<int, List<int?>>` where the dictionary key matches `x`, I want to check the presence of a value `y` in the `List<int?>` and return `true` if `y` is found in this list otherwise return `false`.

Comment: Why aren't you just using `pegMap[x]` or `pegMap.TryGetValue(x, out list)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're completely ignoring the fact that you're using a *dictionary*. It sounds like you might want:

```
public bool CheckMap(int? key, int? checkValue)
{
    List<int?> values;
    if (!pegMap.TryGetValue(key, out values))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return values.Contains(checkValue);
}
```

Comment: I was thinking of a more lambda approach. Little one-liners you know.

Comment: @SohamDasgupta: Why though? Why iterate through the whole of the dictionary when it's *designed* to be an efficient key-value map? If you're sure that the key will be present in the dictionary, you can just use `pegMap[x].Contains(y)` of course.

Comment: I ended up up using your index method. But just for the sake of it, what if the value x is not in the dictionary. Will it raise an error?

Comment: @SohamDasgupta: The code in my answer won't, but `pegMap[x]` would throw KeyNotFoundException

Comment: Thanks Jon. That was some good insight. One More thing Jon, I'm using your answer in some other context where I don't have a key just a value and it should return the key where the value was found. How to go about that.

Comment: @SohamDasgupta: Against what? Still a dictionary? It sounds like you might want to have a dictionary from value to key, if it's unique... otherwise you *will* have to iterate through everything: `pegMap.First(pair => pair.Values.Contains(checkValue)).Key`

Answer (score 1):

`Where` returns a collection, instead you want to check if there is `Any` value that satisfies `x.Equals(key)`

```
Dictionary<int?, List<int?>> pegMap = new Dictionary<int?, List<int?>>()
{
    { 1, new List<int?> {1,2,3} },
    { 2, new List<int?> {4,5,6} },
    { 3, new List<int?> {1,4,5} },
    { 4, new List<int?> {6,7,8} },
};

int? key = 2;
int? value = 4;

if (pegMap.Where(p => p.Key == key).Any(p => p.Value.Any(v => v == value)))
{ 
   // returns true;
}

// You can also use
bool result = pegMap.ContainsKey(key) && pegMap[key].Contains(value);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the difference. I'm really learning the thing.

Answer (score 1):

I think Jon Skeet answer is much more efficient, but if lambda is more important than everything else (gasp), you can try

```
pegMap.Any(x => x.Key == key && x.Value.Contains(disc))
```